# Inexplicably Amplifier Distortion

Tags: amplifier, oscilloscope, gain, distortion

I was just experimenting with some different combinations of transistor stages and got this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPlEod.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 and Q2 represent cascode, where voltage amplification is achieved, then the buffer stage with intent not to decrease the voltage gain just by connecting load straight to the output of cascode stage.

DC currents were biased so that collector current through cascode is approx. 2mA and the collector current through voltage the buffer approx. 1mA. C_comp is meant to be used as compensator of Miller capacitance.

Open loop gain voltage gain of shown amplifier was measured to be a bit more than 10 dB (a bit to low I guess).

With the loads of 1k ohm and 470 ohm, the output signal is pretty stable and its amplitude is decreased from open loop signal for a few tens of mili volts. At the load of 100 ohm and lower, more significant effects start to occur within the circuit.
 Around 30% of negative half of sine gets clipped (without that compensation capacitor much more than 30% + significant output amplitude decrease); so input signal must be lowered to lower voltage levels. Voltage decrease is also significant here, which is rather normal then unexpected. And the last thing is output distortion - it occurs when no person is around the circuit (min. radius half meter from the circuit), but as I approach my hand to the circuit or right above it, at that time the distortion disappears...

*It is not the first time I noticed such version of distortion.

Output amplitude, when the my hand was right above the circuit:
[image]

Output amplitude, when I removed my hand away from the circuit:
[image]

Comment: Looks more like oscillation than distortion.  Holding your hand close to it changes capacitances a bit, just enough to stop the oscillation.  Can't tell you what is oscillating, or why, so no answer.

Comment: Um. Is \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ actually connected as shown in the schematic? Or is the base of \$Q_3\$ connected there? Also, did you design this schematic? If so, can you share your thinking process? If not, where did it come from?

Comment: Q3 only has 1mA DC so it can't drive more than +/- 1mA into the 100 ohm load which will only give you +/-100mV output.  Why do you think you need a compensation capacitor?  That is only needed if you have negative feedback.  You probably have RFoscillation in the emitter follower - try putting a 10-20 ohm resistor in series with the output close to the transistor.

Comment: @jonk I edited that voltage divider so it connected to base of Q3. Well yes, I designed it. I wanted to achieve high impedance input, whereas voltage is also amplified, then transfer that amplified signal to the voltage buffer (wasn't meant to amplify current to higher levels but to prevent the decrease of amplitude on the load, in case of connecting load directly to the output of cascode). I didn't really took to much time designing what gain would I get from the whole circuit, because all of circuits I have been making these days were a total disaster...

Comment: @jonk ....I am pretty happy with the outcome of this case of amplifier. Only thing I have to do is improve that voltage gain, because the output signal was actually attenuated for something like 15dB. I am satisfied with other (usually nothing works, as I design it to work..), unless that undesired oscillation of the circuit.

Comment: @jonk What do you think about it now?

Comment: @KevinWhite The buffer was designed so that there would not be much of a current gain but rather voltage transfer from the cascode to the load. Of course I know there is only 1mA DC flowing through that emitter resistor. But as the lower loads are connected to the output the AC current increases in terms of tens on miliamps.

Comment: @Keno - It cannot output more than +/1mA without distortion into a low resistance load. That is why the negative part of the output is clipped - that occurs when the current in Q3 drops to zero.

Comment: @Keno Do you not see instantly why Kevin is zeroed in on one very serious problem here? You have this very high impedance emitter follower design, using a very high impedance divider to set the base voltage together with a high impedance "pull-down" at the emitter, and you are trying to drive \$100\:\Omega\$? Forget the pull-up capability of \$Q_3\$ (which isn't great, but forget about it for now) and just look at the pull-down capability here? It's nearly non-existent! That load just cannot be hauled around by this stage. It's far too weak.

Comment: So what you are saying is that my emitter follower is having to high input impedance, and there fore the output current cannot be the same as the output current tends to be?

Comment: @Keno Suppose your prior stage attempts to haul downward on the base of \$Q_3\$? Let's say the emitter was at \$10\:\textrm{V}\$. By pulling the base down from \$10.7\:\textrm{V}\$ (using a standard \$V_{BE}\$ for discussion purposes) down to \$9\:\textrm{V}\$, what happens to \$Q_3\$ when its emitter is being held up by voltage on \$C_5\$? It turns off completely, yes? So what is left to start sinking current (to reduce charge) from \$C_5\$? A \$30\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ resistor?? That's more than a 200 second time constant!

Comment: @Keno There is another serious problem with the last stage. When actively driven, it's possible the \$V_{BE}\$ voltage becomes very negative, far exceeding the \$V_{BEO}\$ specification and enough to cause it to avalanche.

Comment: @jonk Reduction of C5? I don't think so - with the C5 of around 220uF, the load amplitude gets negative half cycles 100% clipped and amplitude decreases for even more amount than at the first place.  How is it possible for Vbe to be negative driven if base is biased with DC to 0,6V ? (Look at the edit I made!)

Comment: @Keno I was talking about reducing charge, not reducing the value of \$C_5\$. Oh, well. I'll have to leave it there, for now. Let others have a chance to add their own thoughts with better writing, perhaps. My only other option would be to write a lot more and I am off to sleep now.

Comment: @jonk What is with the time constant? I know it is huge but does that matter here? The problem would be if the cap would be too small and would attenuate lower frequencies, making a high pass filter. Should I decrease the value of Re?

Comment: @Keno It's like you have half-an-understanding about things. Enough to scribble down a topology and compute a few things, but not enough to have any sense of proportion about it. Start with two things. What is your intended "worst case" load that you want to drive; what is the current compliance of your 60 V; what frequencies do you want to handle; and what do you have as a source input driver that is driving the entire system?

Comment: @jonk Of course I have "half-an-understanding about things", if I would understood it all, then I wouldn't be searching for solutions I cannot solve myself :D I want to achieve what is written in the books but the practical examples show effects that even books don't describe. I want experience much of practical work with transistors as amplifiers (for now), that is all.

Comment: @Keno Then answer the questions I asked. If you answer them and if I feel good about the content and context you provide, I may be motivated into a walk through. If you could provide enough details about your goals and constraints, I might find it interesting. I wasn't intending to discuss your current mental state so let's avoiding getting mired there and focus on the important matters -- what exactly are you wanting to achieve here and now?

Comment: @jonk So, lets start. ((I was experimenting with differential amplifier lately as you saw but the results was disastrous; I guess my understanding of that configuration is more like a weak spot for my practical understanding of things.)) First, for variety of input source devices, those have usually low impedance output, if I am right, so input impedance of the first stage of amplifier should be high (I am talking about voltage transfer between the source and the amp); therefore the collector current of CE shouldn't be too high (1 mA is just fine, I guess)....

Comment: @jonk Second, that Q1, I wanted to make it common-base configuration but it rather looks I made a cascade, not cascode (doesn't really matter now, there is some open loop voltage gain). When you want to keep that gain at that point but if the load is connected straight to the output of the first stage then the output of that single stage is rather attenuated than amplified (because of high impedance of collector and very low impedance of the load - lets say between 10 and 100 ohms). ....

Comment: @jonk So, the third thing in this case would be the impedance matching between CE and the load - that is a buffer, a voltage buffer. But since I wasn't looking for powerful amplifier, I wanted to amplify mainly voltage and left the current where it was in the first place - that is why the input impedance of that buffer is so high + I wasn't looking for high currents on the output because the transistors shown in the schematic are high gain; if I would use power transistor, then beta enhancement would be required and therefore darlington amp or something like that....

Comment: @jonk I really didn't want to construct an amplifier with higher output current because of complexity of the whole amplifier - so the whole design was just seeking for a bit of voltage gain. That is all, I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68956/discussion-between-jonk-and-keno).